# Как через cmd произвести обновление иконок в windows 7 которое можно выполнить нажатием пкм+обновить

Tags: cmd

Мне нужно при помощи консоли cmd или конкретнее bat файлы обновить иконки рабочего стола, что можно сделать путём нажатия пкм по рабочему столу и обновить

Comment: гуглите и найдете [refresh desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943021/refresh-desktop-using-batch)